# cambiar de una ventana a otra (programación modular)

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola buenas tardes a todos solicito apoyo, tengo dos ventanas una principal y otra de clientes ambas ventanas tienen barra de menú, la de clientes con una sola opción "Salir" con la que regreso sin problema a la ventana principal, sin embargo al regresar a la principal y seleccionar nuevamente la opción Clientes que es la que me lleva a la ventana Clientes, ya no ejecuta esta opción.

```
#código ven_ppal.py
import tkinter as tk
import mantenimiento as mantenimiento

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import messagebox as mBox

#SE CREA LA VENTANA
win_ppal = tk.Tk()
win_ppal.title("Tecnología para Redes")
win_ppal.geometry("750x550")
win_ppal.resizable(0,0)

#SE CREA BARRA DE MENU
barra_menu = Menu(win_ppal)
win_ppal.config(menu=barra_menu)

#******************** DECLARACION DE FUNCIONES ********************#
def funcion_salir():
    win_ppal.quit()
    win_ppal.destroy()
    exit()

def funcion_clientes():
    win_ppal.withdraw()
    import ven_clientes as ven_clientes
    mantenimiento.ven_ppal.win_ppal.deiconify()
    mantenimiento()

#AGREGAR OPCIONES AL MENU CATALOGOS
menu_catalogos=Menu(barra_menu)
menu_catalogos.add_command(label="Clientes", command=funcion_clientes)
menu_catalogos.add_command(label="Equipo")
barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Catálogos", menu=menu_catalogos)

#AGREGAR OPCIONES AL MENU ORDENES
menu_ordenes = Menu(barra_menu)
menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Crear")
menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Actualizar")
menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Status")
menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Imprimir")
barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Órden de Servicio", menu=menu_ordenes)

#OPCION SALIR
menu_salir = Menu(barra_menu)
barra_menu.add_command(label="Salir", command=funcion_salir)

win_ppal.mainloop()


#código ven_clien.py
import tkinter as tk
import ven_ppal as ven_ppal
import mantenimiento as mantenimiento

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import messagebox as mBox

#SE CREA LA VENTANA
win_clien = tk.Tk()
win_clien.title("Tecnología para Redes --- CLIENTES")
win_clien.geometry("850x700")
win_clien.resizable(0,0)

#******************** DECLARACION DE FUNCIONES ********************#
def funcion_salcli():
        win_clien.withdraw()
        mantenimiento.ven_ppal.win_ppal.deiconify()

#******************** BARRA DE MENU ********************#
barra_menu = Menu(win_clien)
win_clien.config(menu=barra_menu)
menu_salcli=Menu(barra_menu)
barra_menu.add_command(label='Salir', command=funcion_salcli)

win_clien.mainloop()

#código mantenmiento.py
import ven_ppal as ven_ppal
```

..... De antemano gracias, considero que mi lógica de estructurar no la tengo bien definida acepto sugerencias...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no se que tiene que ver programacion modular con todo esto... si no pones que es python, nadie se entera en que lenguaje estas programando...

Comment: gracias, ya corregí los errores, ahora me aroja un error por la consola

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rmbg60/Python3x/TkinterPython/ven_ppal.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ven_clientes
  File "/home/rmbg60/Python3x/TkinterPython/ven_clientes.py", line 48, in <module>
    btn_creacli = tk.Button(nueva_ven_clientes, text="Crear cliente", command=funcion_creacli)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2650, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2566, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2535, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema principal es que todo el código encargado de definir y ejecutar tu ventana "cliente" lo defines globalmente en su módulo y luego haces uso de los `imports` para ejecutar dicho código y abrir la ventana.

Cuando importas un módulo en Python el código a nivel global es ejecutado la primera vez, si vuelves a invocar el `import` sobre un modulo previamente importado ese código ya no se ejecuta de nuevo porque el modulo ya esta importado. Esto hace que en tu caso la ventana no se cree de nuevo después de la primera vez.

Hay formas de recargar un modulo previamente importado, pero en tu caso simplemente no uses el `import` para esto y evita las variables globales si no hay una razón justificada para ello.

La forma mas simple de solucionar tu problema sin tocar apenas tu código actual es englobar todo el código encargado de crear tus ventanas en una función, cada vez que requieras crear una nueva ventana solo llama a la función. Puedes usar funciones `lambda` para pasar argumentos a las callbacks y poder usar los objetos, definidos antes globalmente, en ellas.

Otra cosa que debes tener en cuenta es que solo debes tener una ventana principal en tu app. En vez de instanciar una segunda `tkinter.Tk` y llamar de nuevo a su mainloop, usa `tkinter.Toplevel`.

Por ultimo, defines que debe pasar en tu ventana cuando pulsas la opción `Salir` del menú, pero debes tener en cuenta que el usuario puede también pulsar el botón `X` de la barra de titulo o usar otro método proporcionado por el SO y su gestor de ventanas para cerrar las ventanas. Para hacer mas consistente el comportamiento y evitar errores puedes usar la señal `<Destroy>` generada en estos casos y enlazarla a tu función.

### ven_ppal.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu

import ven_clientes


def nueva_ven_ppal():
    #SE CREA LA VENTANA
    win_ppal = tk.Tk()
    win_ppal.title("Tecnología para Redes")
    win_ppal.geometry("750x550")
    win_ppal.resizable(0,0)

    #SE CREA BARRA DE MENU
    barra_menu = Menu(win_ppal)
    win_ppal.config(menu=barra_menu)

    #AGREGAR OPCIONES AL MENU CATALOGOS
    menu_catalogos=Menu(barra_menu)
    menu_catalogos.add_command(
        label="Clientes", command=lambda: funcion_clientes(win_ppal)
    )
    menu_catalogos.add_command(label="Equipo")
    barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Catálogos", menu=menu_catalogos)

    #AGREGAR OPCIONES AL MENU ORDENES
    menu_ordenes = Menu(barra_menu)
    menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Crear")
    menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Actualizar")
    menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Status")
    menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Imprimir")
    barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Órden de Servicio", menu=menu_ordenes)

    #OPCION SALIR
    menu_salir = Menu(barra_menu)
    barra_menu.add_command(
        label="Salir", command=lambda: funcion_salir(win_ppal)
    )

    win_ppal.mainloop()

#******************** DECLARACION DE FUNCIONES ********************#
def funcion_salir(win_ppal):
    win_ppal.destroy()

def funcion_clientes(win_ppal):
    ven_clientes.nueva_ven_clientes(win_ppal)
```

### ven_clientes.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu


def nueva_ven_clientes(win_ppal):
    #SE CREA LA VENTANA
    win_clien = tk.Toplevel(win_ppal)
    win_clien.title("Tecnología para Redes --- CLIENTES")
    win_clien.geometry("850x700")
    win_clien.resizable(0, 0)

    #******************** BARRA DE MENU ********************#
    barra_menu = Menu(win_clien)
    win_clien.config(menu=barra_menu)
    menu_salcli=Menu(barra_menu)
    barra_menu.add_command(label='Salir', command=win_clien.destroy)
    
    win_clien.bind("<Destroy>", lambda event: funcion_salcli(event, win_ppal))
    win_ppal.withdraw()

#******************** DECLARACION DE FUNCIONES ********************#
def funcion_salcli(event, win_ppal):
    win_ppal.deiconify()
    event.widget.destroy()
```

### mantenimiento.py

```
from ven_ppal import nueva_ven_ppal

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nueva_ven_ppal()
```

Supongo que `mantenimiento.py` es tu modulo principal.

Otra opción es usar POO (programación orientada a objetos) para estructurar tu app:

### ven_ppal.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from ven_clientes import VenClientes


class VenPPAL(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.title("Tecnología para Redes")
        self.geometry("750x550")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        
        #SE CREA BARRA DE MENU
        barra_menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=barra_menu)
        
        #AGREGAR OPCIONES AL MENU CATALOGOS
        menu_catalogos = tk.Menu(barra_menu)
        menu_catalogos.add_command(
            label="Clientes", command=self.abrir_ventana_clientes
        )
        menu_catalogos.add_command(label="Equipo")
        barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Catálogos", menu=menu_catalogos)

        #AGREGAR OPCIONES AL MENU ORDENES
        menu_ordenes = tk.Menu(barra_menu)
        menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Crear")
        menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Actualizar")
        menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Status")
        menu_ordenes.add_command(label="Imprimir")
        barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Órden de Servicio", menu=menu_ordenes)

        #OPCION SALIR
        menu_salir = tk.Menu(barra_menu)
        barra_menu.add_command(label="Salir", command=self.salir)

    def salir():
        self.destroy()

    def abrir_ventana_clientes(self):
        VenClientes(self)
```

### ven_clientes.py

```
import tkinter as tk


class VenClientes(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.bind("<Destroy>", self.salir)
        
        self.title("Tecnología para Redes --- CLIENTES")
        self.geometry("850x700")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        
        #******************** BARRA DE MENU ********************#
        barra_menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=barra_menu)
        menu_salcli=tk.Menu(barra_menu)
        barra_menu.add_command(label='Salir', command=self.destroy)

    def salir(self, event):
        if event.widget is self:        
            self.master.deiconify()
```

### mantenimiento.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from ven_ppal import VenPPAL

if __name__ == "__main__":
    VenPPAL().mainloop()
```